# Querying CheckedListBox is returning elements that were not checked

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a form which will perform `iisreset` to remote servers.
The server name I'm getting from the user who needs to select them from a checkbox list.

My problem is that even if the user choses one server, the code processes it like he chose 2.

```
if ($CBLUKSTG.Visible -Match $true)
{
    [array]$chosenServers = $CBLUKSTG.Items
    foreach ($item in $chosenServers)
    {
        Invoke-Command –ComputerName $chosenServers –ScriptBlock { iisreset    /noforce }
        Invoke-Command –ComputerName $chosenServers –ScriptBlock { iisreset /status }
        Write-Host "IIS restarted succefully on $item"
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that you are calling two times your `Invoke-Command`. Shouldn't it be called only once ?

Comment: Please paste your checkbox design code as well. Also if possible show $CBLUKSTG codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is coming from this line: `[array]$chosenServers = $CBLUKSTG.Items`. Looking at [TechNet for `.Items`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see that it

> Gets the collection of items in this CheckedListBox.

That would return *all* items from the list. What you need to be doing is only returning `[array]$chosenServers = $CBLUKSTG.CheckedItems`. So you should be checking [CheckedItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Collection of **checked items** in this CheckedListBox.

Comment: thank you very much ! somehow i missed this option.
last question - how can I check the iis status after restarting ?